Migration of multiple tables with different schemas in SSIS
I’m looking to migrate several tables from one database to another using SSIS in SQL Server 2019. The tables have different schemas.
I would like to know how to set up an SSIS package that uses a loop to process each table individually, while using a single OLE DB source and destination.
If anyone has tips, steps, or resources, I would greatly appreciate it!
Thank you in advance!

If this is a one-off operation I would just use the export data wizard in SQL Server Management Studio. Right click on your database, pick Tasks> context menu and the Export Data...
You can pick an OLEDB source and destination and select the tables that you want to transfer in the GUI.
more details here
https://www.sqlshack.com/importexport-data-sql-server-using-sql-server-import-export-wizard/
including that it generates the necessary SSIS package which one can opt to save.
